# What are the standard tools to align printed strings in R?

Tags: r, string, printing, alignment, cat

Here is a series of `cat` statements

```
words = c("Hello","bar","ROCKnROLL","R","Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious")
for (i in 1:length(words))
{
    cat(paste0(words[i], "\t: ",nchar(words[i]),"\n"))
}

Hello   : 5
bar : 3
ROCKnROLL   : 9
R   : 1
Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious  : 34
```

How would I do to align them like this

```
Hello                               : 5
bar                                 : 3
ROCKnROLL                           : 9
R                                   : 1
Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious  : 34
```

or like this

```
                             Hello  : 5
                               bar  : 3
                         ROCKnROLL  : 9
                                 R  : 1
Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious  : 34
```

or eventually like this

```
             Hello                  : 5
              bar                   : 3
           ROCKnROLL                : 9
               R                    : 1
Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious  : 34
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
words = c("Hello","bar","ROCKnROLL","R","Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious")
for (i in 1:length(words)) {
  print(sprintf("%-40s:%d", words[i], nchar(words[i])))
}
```

with output:

```
[1] "Hello                                   :5"
[1] "bar                                     :3"
[1] "ROCKnROLL                               :9"
[1] "R                                       :1"
[1] "Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious      :34"
```

Comment: The `for()` loop is unnecessary. `sprintf("%-40s:%d", words, nchar(words))`

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a fixed-width file. base R does not have this function (only `read.fwf`), but `gdata::write.fwf` will work

```
## create a data frame to write
words = c("Hello","bar","ROCKnROLL","R","Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious")
dat <- data.frame(words = words, sep = ':', nchar = nchar(words))

## write.fwf without a file name will print to the console
(co <- capture.output(gdata::write.fwf(dat, width = c(max(nchar(words)), 1, 3), justify = 'r'))[-1])
# [1] "                             Hello :   5" "                               bar :   3"
# [3] "                         ROCKnROLL :   9" "                                 R :   1"
# [5] "Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious :  34"

## cat it
cat(co, sep = '\n')

#                              Hello :   5
#                                bar :   3
#                          ROCKnROLL :   9
#                                  R :   1
# Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious :  34
```

You can change the justification to get the other alignments

```
cat(capture.output(gdata::write.fwf(dat, width = c(max(nchar(words)), 1, 3), justify = 'c'))[-1], sep = '\n')
#               Hello                :   5
#                bar                 :   3
#             ROCKnROLL              :   9
#                 R                  :   1
# Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious :  34

cat(capture.output(gdata::write.fwf(dat, width = c(max(nchar(words)), 1, 3), justify = 'l'))[-1], sep = '\n')
# Hello                              :   5
# bar                                :   3
# ROCKnROLL                          :   9
# R                                  :   1
# Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious :  34
```